# Optional generic that extends interface

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I have a exported abstract class that currently has one generic. I however need two generics now. I do not want to change all the excising classes that currently use this class. So I would like to add a optional generic class that extends a interface.

This is what I currently have

```
export abstract class SharedShell<T extends IBase, T1 extends IBase> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {}
```

What is the best way to make T1 optional? I tried doing the following

```
export abstract class SharedShell<T extends IBase, T1 extends IBase | Undefined = Undefined> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {}
```

However this is causing a type error.

```
'IBase' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T1', but 'T1' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IBase'.
```

This is where I'm stuck, how can I best solve this?

[TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQCFMBnPAbwCg4bEATALjiQFcBbAIzQG5raA3TABsWwJiRhRkAc14BfSpQD0SuABUAFghKIdMDXjBCcwDRCF00cdNAIBlDZijA6dtPwS44lUJFiIUNCwvfAcnFzcoD1wAHjU4UFQkOh0iUmAAPjhyOV5FH3BoeEwOCSgceGxjEh0w51cDISE4hJAklIJiMgAadQBGVvbUrrwAHzgWZOB0ZBc4AF4JqZmkFyyqWjhsCCQylmwYaAAKMClBVDhLGEwEIUjosXtHevvPYBbxtT6M7r5N--%20pwQ5zwQm0MFeuCYoWeEXcbziPz%20cAAlNkFAogA)

Comment: Can you please provide a complete reproducible example i.e using TS playground? From your code I can't see the error:

Comment: @mbdavis I added a example to the original post.

Comment: Thank you! So to clarify - you want detailService to be `ISharedService<T | T1>` when `T1` is provided, and just `ISharedService<T>` otherwise?

Comment: @mbdavis yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have to use your `SharedShell` as declared, then I'd use a conditional type like the  [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to turn `T1` into something suitable:

```
export abstract class SharedShell<T extends IBase, T1 extends IBase | undefined = undefined> {
    constructor(private detailService: ISharedService<T | Extract<T1, IBase>>,
        private listService: ISharedService<T>,
    ) { }
}
```

If `T1` is `undefined`, then `Extract<T1, IBase>` will be `never`, and `T | never` is just `T`... so that works how you want.  If `T1` is some union (e.g., `SomeSubtypeOfIBase | undefined`), then `Extract<T1, IBase>` will include only the part of it assignable to `IBase` (e.g., `SomeSubtypeOfIBase`).

---

I'm not sure what purpose the second parameter `T1` serves, so the following suggestion might not be tenable, but: you might want to just have `T1` default to `never` and not include `undefined` in the domain of `T1`.  When you do this, the type `T | T1` will always be assignable to `IBase` and things will just work:

```
export abstract class SharedShell<T extends IBase, T1 extends IBase = never> {
    constructor(private detailService: ISharedService<T | T1>,
        private listService: ISharedService<T>,
    ) { }
}
```

Again, without more of an example surrounding how `T1` is used, I can't be sure if that will help.  But it's much simpler.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQCFMBnPAbwCg4bEATALjiQFcBbAIzQG5raA3TABsWwJiRhRkAc14BfSpQD0SuABUAFghKIdMDXjBCcwDRCF00cdNAIBlDZijA6dtPwS44lUJFiIUNCwvfAcnFzcoD1wAHjU4UFQkOh0iUmAAPjhyODleRV9oeEwOCSgceGxjEh0w51cDISE4hJAklIJiMgAadQBGVvbUrrwAHzgWZOB0ZBc4AF4JqZmkFyyqWjhsCCQylmwYaAAKMClBVDhLGEwEIUjosXtHevvPYBbxgFE28oO4vt6aTIGQy3T4mxopwQ5zwQm0MFeuCYoWeEXcbzioO8mwAlNlcpQFD5wEU4CUyhUttVaqiGsAmn0WolgMlhulemoBszWZ10gtmMB+Gh1uCtjs9gdjlCYZdgNdbojHijwq50bF4uNOaDRZtpZgLnCJIrkXU0VEMWptbj8QoiUA)